# XMLSerializer throws Access Denied exception when code runs on web server but not locally

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

When I run the following line of code locally it runs succesfully. When I upload the code to the Arvixe web server I get the exception. I can read and write the temp folder  as found by Path.GetTempPath()

I understand that XMLSerializer needs a temp path to create .DLLs. Does ASP.NET use a different temp path that it does not have permissions? I have compiled as Generate Serialization Assemblies Auto, Off and On to no avail. It must be a server setting as it runs on another Arvixe server but I dont know what to ask the server admins to do.

```
'This is the code line that  causes the exception:
Sub Test
  Dim formatter = New XmlSerializer(GetType(TestSMTPClass))
End Sub`

'This is a simple class we are trying to serialize
Public Class TestSMTPClass
    Property ServerIP As String
    Property Port As String

End Class
```

Throws this exception

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
ex.ToString
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.Win32.Fusion.ReadCache(ArrayList alAssems, String name, UInt32 nFlag)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.EnumerateCache(AssemblyName partialName)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(String partialName, Evidence securityEvidence)
at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(Type type, String defaultNamespace, XmlSerializerImplementation& contract)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
at OCC_Competition.TestSMTP.btnTestCode_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Since your code runs under another account when hosting on IIS, the temp folder indeed differs. More differences you should know can be found in https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Ensure that your application pool identity has the proper permission for the website root folder. Also, be sure about your application pool identity user before applying for permission.

Comment: Hello. Were you able to get this resolved? I am having the exact same issue. It was working until somewhat recently. I've submitted a ticket to Arvixe, but they haven't been able to resolve it.